# Find perpendicular distance from a turtle

Tags: netlogo

Is there some procedure to find the perpendicular distance from a turtle. Preferably the procedure is same for positions of turtles computing.
[image]

Comment: The answer is to do the math.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Pythagorean theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem) to get perpendicular distance.

Comment: I just wanted to use to an built method instead of coding it myself for efficiency and less clutter in code.

Comment: There is no inbuilt code for this, upto my knowledge. Reason for it not been there? It is because it is too easy to code :)

Comment: Ohk. I had asked because similar procedure like in-radius and in-cone exist. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by perpendicular distance since your diagram just seems to want the distance between the turtles. If so, you can use the `distance` primitive.